# Global local array in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have 2 type of contact list.

1. My contacts
2. priority contacts

Both contact may have common contacts and now I want to save contacts without duplication .

How can I achieve this in sencha touch?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need two separate stores for this. Store all your contacts in one store and use some properties to detect whether contact is priority/favorite or both.

UPDATE: Here is filtering example. This would filter second store and leave only records with field `name` not found in the first store.

```
st1 = ...
st2 = ...

st2.filter(function(r) {
   return st1.findExact('name', r.get('name')) < 0;
});
```

Comment: I am getting 2 contact store through rest api so I can't change it and I want to merge both store in global cache without duplication and then I will do the filteration on the merged store and show in list .

Comment: Then you need to combine them together. You can create a filter in one store that would give you only records that don't exist in other, and then add this result to combined store. Let me know if you need example on how to properly filter it.

Comment: How will I do filter in this case? I have to filter the records from the combine array whether it belong to contact list or priority list. Please give me filter example.

Comment: Account: Object
AccountName: "18000 Contacts Account"
AccountTier: null
Contact: Object
Id: "003E000000VGEPxIAP"
Name: "18000Contacts 11872"
__proto__: Object
EmailFields: null
FirstName: "18000Contacts"
FlagColor: "ORANGE"
FlagLabel: "35"
LastName: "11872"
PhoneFields: null
PriorityIndicator: null
listId: "MYCONTACTS"

Comment: Account: Object
AccountName: "WestLB Equity Markets"
AccountTier: null
Contact: Object
Id: "003E000000VFtgvIAD"
Name: "Achim Johnigk"
__proto__: Object
EmailFields: null
FirstName: "Achim"
FlagColor: null
FlagLabel: null
LastName: "Johnigk"
PhoneFields: null
PriorityIndicator: null
listId: "a0LE0000000yeFRMAY"

Comment: Above are 2 contact record from each contact and there is one unique item which is contact id in it and there is list id which tells me that it belongs to which record.

Answer (score 0):

Try and look for the functions union and unique in the sencha documentation. http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/#!/api/Ext.Array